# Listas não estão sendo renderizadas corretamente nos posts

Tags: bug, status-pronto, markdown

As listas não estão sendo corretamente formatadas nos *posts*. Isso acontece tanto com listas numeradas quanto com não-numeradas.

Exemplo, [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052), tem uma lista com o Markdown assim:

```
1. como o code point [U+00E1 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e1) (`á`)
2. como uma combinação de dois code points:
    - a letra `a` (sem acento): [U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061)
    - o acento agudo (` ́`): [U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301)
```

Mas atualmente está sendo renderizado assim:

[image: lista sem formatação]

---

Aliás, na [respectiva pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) também dá para ver o mesmo problema. O Markdown:

```
- *encoding*
- *charset* (*character set*, *character map*, *code set*)
- *collation*
- *code page*
- *plane* (BMP, SMP, etc.)
- *code point*
- *octet*
```

Está aparecendo assim:

[image: outra lista sem formatação]

---

Testando aqui no meta, com o Markdown:

```
- item 1
- item 2
    - item 2.1
    - item 2.2
- item 3
```

Fica assim:

- item 1
- item 2

  - item 2.1
  - item 2.2
- item 3

Caso seja corrigido acima, segue imagem de como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Testado no Ubuntu 20.04, Chrome 91.0.4472.77.

No celular - iOS 14, Chrome - o problema não ocorre, veja a diferença:

[image]

[image]

Comment: *Cross post* (acabei de ver no meta.SE): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366240/401803

Comment: Acabei de testar e aparentemente esta normal agora. Provavelmente o "build" já tenha sido propagado para todos sites.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento É, vi no meta.SE que já foi corrigido.